# ios embbeded stackviews and constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, uistackview

***How the view should be looking***:-
[image]

I am trying to make a view controller with the above view. I have 2 stack views (The gray line) each containing 3 stack views (black line). Inside each stack I have UIImageView (yellow line) and text label (red line).

**The problem:** I am only making constraints for the most outter stack view, but IB complains I should also make constraints for the inner stack views (Missing X and Y coordinates..).
Can someone help me with this ? I tried all kinds of constraints and nothing was working as epxected. My goal is that the final view will be looking like the image.

Comment: Did you tried Height and Width constraints for inner stackviews?

Comment: Actually not, I was trying to make constraints between the inner stack views, like the middle stack view bottom equals low stack view top + constant, but somehow that didn't work also.

I thought that when using stack views I should only make constraints to the most outter stack view.

Comment: Try to use vertical spacing constraint between middle stack view and top and  bottom stack view and fixed width to all the three stack views.